# How to use @Where in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

Searched for a few hours, but I'm stuck in a my learning curve for PlayFramework with JPA. I'm building a sample website where posts can be made. But these posts can have the states:

- PostDraft (post is a draft, do not publish)
- PostPublished (post can be published)

These states are stored in a seperate table. Obviously, the draft state posts **should not be visible yet.**

So I have these classes:

- Page class (getting the page information from table, 1 page can have multiple posts)
- Posts class (posts can be in draft and published)

In my page class I have:

```
@Column(name="POSTS_REF")
@Where(clause="PostPublished")
private List<Posts> userPosts;
```

But this is not working! So, how can I specifify a where clause, to load only the posts that are in published state without using JPQL??

Thanks!

**UPDATE: 2011-10-11**

Table: *Posts* with columns:
 - id
 - title
 - state_ref  (reference to the ID of States table)
 - content

Table: *States* with columns:
 - id
 - statename

So I want to say something like:

```
select * 
from posts inner join states on posts.state_ref = states.id
where states.statename = 'PostPublished'
```

**UPDATE 2011-10-13**

This is my current modification, in my page class: but it does not work either.

```
/** link to the states */
@JoinColumn(name = "STATES_REF")
@OneToOne
@Where(clause = "states.statename = 'PostPublished'")
public MyState state;
```

**UPDATE 2012-02-13**
Emt's answer worked for me after all.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try something like:

```
@Column(name="POSTS_REF")
@Where(clause="state='PostPublished'")
private List<Posts> userPosts;
```

or

```
@Column(name="POSTS_REF")
@Where(clause="PostPublished=true")
private List<Posts> userPosts;
```

depending on the status field type on your `Post` entity.

Comment: What if in @Where(clause="PostPublished=true"), i want to take value from a property of the model instead of hardcoding the value?

Answer (score 8):

The where clause must be a complete condition - something like this.   Assuming that state is a property on the post.

```
@Column(name="POSTS_REF")
@Where(clause="state = 'PostPublished'")
private List<Posts> userPosts;
```

**EDIT**

Based on the data model - the following should work.  I wouldn't recommend using it. Don't map the posts collection - just have a reference to Page from the POsts class, add a method to your DAO to retrieve the published posts for a page by using HQL or criteria query.

```
@Column(name="POSTS_REF")
@Where(clause="exists (select id from states where state_ref = states.id and states.statename = 'PostPublished')")
private List<Posts> userPosts;
```

Comment: Hi gkamal, thanks for answering but the this is not working for me. I will update my question with the data model.

Comment: Hi gkamal, I cannot use this since I have a states table and all the states are in this table. So also states of persons, and states of comments etc... :-(

Answer (score 2):

The `where` condition must contain a database column name:

```
@Where(clause="state = 'PostPublished'")
```

Here the `state` column name is in DB and not in the Hibernate mapping.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. This is on the StudentInfo.java

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "studentInfo")
@Where(clause = "active_ind = 'Y'")
private Set<Courses> courses = new HashSet<>();
```

The 'active_ind' is a Column in Courses Table, it's not attribute name in the Course.java class. The Tables are
StudentInfo:

> - student_id
> - student_name
> - etc..

Courses:

> - course_id
> - course_name
> - student_id (Foreign Key)
> - active_ind
> - etc..