# Hibernate: limit query with one-to-many

Tags: hibernate

For example, I have the `Service` entity:

```java
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "service")
public List<ServiceStatus> getServiceStatuses() {
    return serviceStatuses;
}
```

and the `ServiceStatus` entity:

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "service", nullable = false)
public Service getService() {
    return service;
}

@Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

Now I need to query all the `Service` objects so that each of it has only those `ServiceStatus` objects where `ServiceStatus.date` is between `date1` and `date2`. That is, if there are 10 `ServiceStatus` objects with the proper date, the `serviceStatuses` list will have only those 10 objects and nothing more. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using @Filter:

```
@FilterDef(name = "dateFilter", parameters = {
        @ParamDef(name = "date1", type = "date"),
        @ParamDef(name = "date2", type = "date") })
@Filter(name = "dateFilter", condition = "date >= :date1 and date <= :date2")
```

and applying it to session:

```
session.enableFilter("dateFilter")
                .setParameter("date1", date1)
                .setParameter("date2", date2);
```

BTW, when working with Hibernate, what should I use for queries: it's own mechanism or "raw" SQL like "inner join" in this case?

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of [`@Where`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700071/how-to-use-where-in-jpa-hibernate) clause:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "service")
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = 'N'")
List<ServiceStatus> serviceStatuses = new ArrayList<ServiceStatus>();
```

The above implementation allows you to filter records which are `is_deleted = N`. Similarly you can write your own implementation.

Comment: Yes, this works when the clause is static, but can I use parameters like this: "date >= :date1 and date <= :date2"?

Comment: How does the where annotation work for is null or is not null ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Restrictions.le("date2",date2) and Restrictions.gt("date1",date1) while querying.
see this link.

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/

following is also very useful

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: ok , i am adding code as an another answer,So that it will be properly indented.

Answer (score 1):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Service.class);
if(date1!=null){
    criteria.add(Expression.ge("serviceStatuses.date1",date1));
}
if(date2!=null){
    criteria.add(Expression.le("serviceStatuses.date2",date2));
}
return criteria.list();
```

got it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HQL to create query for this case.

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/