# JPA join based on status column?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Is it possibile to define somehow a relationship based on a status column?

```
Table A: id, valueA
Table B: id, refIdA, valueB, status
```

So in class A I would like to fetch only B where the status is active. Fetching with `em.find(id, A.class)`. Is there way to define that within the entity?

```
@Entity
public class A {
  ...
  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "refIdA")
  private List<B> b;
  ...
}
```

Comment: You CANNOT do that with JPA. You join on the FK always. Falling back to implementation specials loses portability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Eclipse Link one solution is to use `@AdditionalCriteria`. However this annotations is not applicable on a member. But for my usecase that is ok. So annotating `B` filters all `B`'s for `Status.ACTIVE`.

```
@Entity
@AdditonalCriteria("this.status = com.example.Status.ACTIVE")
public class B {
  ...
}
```

Thanks to [Peter L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1408360/peter-l).

Answer (score 0):

Try `@Where`. There are plenty of examples on the site on how to use it, i.e. [How to use @Where in JPA Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700071/how-to-use-where-in-jpa-hibernate)

Comment: Thank you, that lead me into the right direction. `@Where` is not availabele in EclipseLink, but it is possible by `@AdditionalCriteria`