# How to add global where clause for all find methods of Spring data JPA with Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We are working on web application using Spring data JPA with hibernate.

In the application there is a field of compid in each entity.
Which means in every DB call (Spring Data methods) will have to be checked with the compid.

I need a way that, this "where compid = ?" check to be injected automatically for every find method. 
So that we won't have to specifically bother about compid checks.

Is this possible to achieve from Spring Data JPA framework?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe Hibernate‘s annotation `@Where` will help you. It adds the passed condition to any JPA queries related to the entity. For example

```
@Entity
@Where(clause = "isDeleted='false'")
public class Customer {
    //...
    @Column
    private Boolean isDeleted;
}
```

More info: [1](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-where-clause), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700071/how-to-use-where-in-hibernate)

Comment: thanks for responding,
but in @Where annotation I have to add it on each entity class. and i want to avoid this type of mechanism. 
Is it possible to do like this?

Where
repo.findAll();

Comment: Do you have a base super class for all such entities? You can move field `compid` and `@Where` annotation there...

Comment: There is an open issue for "generic query augmentation" which is the type of functionality you're after but it's not made much progress https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-293. I think the `@Where` annotation added to a superclass is you're best bet - as it is a Hibernate specific annotation it doesn't work with the Spring Data repositories so it'll need to go on the entities.

Comment: @Zeeshan don't forget to accept /upvote the answer ))

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Abhijit Sarkar.

You can achieve your goal hibernate listeners and aspects. I can suggest the following : 
create an annotation `@Compable` (or whatever you call it) to mark service methods 
create CompAspect which should be a bean and `@Aspect`. It should have something like this

```
@Around("@annotation(compable)")`
    public Object enableClientFilter(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Compable compable) throws Throwable {
        Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
        try {
            if (session.isOpen()) {
                session.enableFilter("compid_filter_name")
                        .setParameter("comp_id", your_comp_id);
            }
            return pjp.proceed();
        } finally {
            if (session.isOpen()) {
                session.disableFilter("filter_name");
            }
        }
    }

em  - EntityManager
```

3)Also you need to provide hibernate filters. If you use annotation this can look like this:

```
@FilterDef(name="compid_filter_name", parameters=@ParamDef(name="comp_id", type="java.util.Long"))
@Filters(@Filter(name="compid_filter_name", condition="comp_id=:comp_id"))
```

So your condition `where compid = ?` will be `@Service` method below

```
   @Compable
    someServicweMethod(){
     List<YourEntity> l = someRepository.findAllWithNamesLike("test");
    }
```

That's basically it for Selects,
For updates/deletes this scheme requires an `EntityListener`.

Comment: this is an excellent idea , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like other people have said there is no set method for this

One option is to look at Query by example - from the spring data documentation -

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setFirstname("Dave");
Example<Person> example = Example.of(person);
```

So you could default compid in the object, or parent JPA object

Another option is a custom repository

Answer (score 0):

I can contribute a 50% solution. 50% because it seems to be not easy to wrap [Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods). Also custom JPA queries are an issue for this global approach. If the standard finders are sufficient it is possible to extend an own `SimpleJpaRepository`:

```
public class CustomJpaRepositoryIml<T, ID extends Serializable> extends
    SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> {

private JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation;

@Autowired
public CustomJpaRepositoryIml(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation,
                              EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
}



private Sort applyDefaultOrder(Sort sort) {
    if (sort == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (sort.isUnsorted()) {
        return Sort.by("insert whatever is a default").ascending();
    }
    return sort;
}

private Pageable applyDefaultOrder(Pageable pageable) {
    if (pageable.getSort().isUnsorted()) {
        Sort defaultSort = Sort.by("insert whatever is a default").ascending();
        pageable = PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), defaultSort);
    }
    return pageable;
}


@Override
public Optional<T> findById(ID id) {
    Specification<T> filterSpec = filterOperatorUserAccess();
    if (filterSpec == null) {
        return super.findById(id);
    }
    return findOne(filterSpec.and((Specification<T>) (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Path<?> path = root.get(entityInformation.getIdAttribute());
        return criteriaBuilder.equal(path, id);
    }));
}

@Override
protected <S extends T> TypedQuery<S> getQuery(Specification<S> spec, Class<S> domainClass, Sort sort) {
    sort = applyDefaultOrder(sort);
    Specification<T> filterSpec = filterOperatorUserAccess();
    if (filterSpec != null) {
        spec = (Specification<S>) filterSpec.and((Specification<T>) spec);
    }
    return super.getQuery(spec, domainClass, sort);
}

}
```

This implementation is picked up e.g. by adding it to the Spring Boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = CustomJpaRepositoryIml.class)
public class ServerStart {
...
```

If you need this kind of filtering also for Querydsl it is also possible to implement and register a `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`.