# Filter JPA by new Boolean without updating all the JPA single derived query method Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have to add a new Boolean field as isInactive for an existing JPA entity and then filter all the JPA results where this Boolean is false. How to achieve this without updating every single derived query method? (as there are over 40)

The entity is as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bbser_inventory")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InventoryEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "bbser_inventory_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "bbser_inventory_gen", sequenceName = "bbser_inventory_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "inventory_id")
    private Long inventoryId;

    @Column(name = "unit_id")
    private String unitId;

    .
    .
    . 
@Column(name = "is_inactive")
@ColumnDefault("false")
private Boolean isInactive;
```

Some of the derived query methods are as follows

```
etc .
    .
    .
    List<InventoryEntity> findByUnitId(String unitId);

    List<InventoryEntity> findByUnitIdAndHospitalIdAndGroupId(String unitId, Integer hospitalId, Integer groupId);

    List<InventoryEntity> findByUnitIdAndStatusAliasIn(String unitId, Collection<String> status);

    List<InventoryEntity> findByUnitIdAndHospitalIdAndGroupIdAndStatusAliasIn(String unitId, Integer hospitalId, Integer groupId, Collection<String> status);

    List<InventoryEntity> findByStatusAlias(String statusAlias);
    .
    .
    .etc
```

Comment: There is a useful discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952919/how-to-add-global-where-clause-for-all-find-methods-of-spring-data-jpa-with-hibe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using **@Where** annotation on top of the class.

I added `@Where(clause = "is_inactive = false")` as following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bbser_inventory")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Where(clause = "is_inactive = false")
public class InventoryEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "bbser_inventory_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "bbser_inventory_gen", sequenceName = "bbser_inventory_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "inventory_id")
    private Long inventoryId;

    @Column(name = "unit_id")
    private String unitId;

    .
    .
    . 
@Column(name = "is_inactive")
@ColumnDefault("false")
private Boolean isInactive;
```