# Hibernate where condition on Join

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to join a table with 2 conditions, userId and guideId are the same in both tables.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id",insertable =false, updatable = false)
@Where(clause = "guide_id = guide_id") <-- this isn't working
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private UserInvite userInvite;
```

Is this the right way to go about it?

I found some documentation around filters but this seems like an overkill. Is there a simple solution using the Where annotation?

Comment: no I want the guide_id in the current table to match the guide_id in the UserInvite table

Comment: hope this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700071/how-to-use-where-in-hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `@JoinColumns` while specifying the relation:

```
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id",insertable =false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="guide_id", referencedColumnName="guide_id",insertable =false, updatable = false)
    })
```

If you are still adamant on using `@Where` , try using below clause:

```
@Where(clause = "guide_id = userInvite.guide_id")
```

Please make sure that **guide_id**  is mapped as a field in your current entity where you are creating the relation

In case if the above clause doesn't work,let me know will figure it out in some other way

Comment: Seems to work thank you! I had tried with JoinColumns but missed the referenceColumnName part.