# One to One relationship with the last recent record

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two entity

```
   class EntityOne{   
        @OneToOne
        @Where(???????????????)
        private EntityOneStatusTracker status;
   }

    class EntityOneStatusTracker{
        private Long id;
        private Date date;

        @ManyToOne
        private EntityOne entityOne;
   }
```

I want Entity One to reference only the last recent record of the entity two using where clause, is this possible?

Comment: Yes, look at documentation for `@Where`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700071/how-to-use-where-in-hibernate

Comment: @MohammadAdil I want to select by date and I want the last added one how?