# How to Select Only Specific Children in One to Many Relation in JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

Here below is a simple model for a pet shop...

**Pet Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pet")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public abstract class Pet {

  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "birth_date", nullable = false)
  private LocalDate birthDate;

  @Column(name = "death_date")
  private LocalDate deathDate;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "pet_shop_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  private PetShop petShop;

  public void setPetShop(PetShop petShop) {
    setPetShop(petShop, true);
  }

  public void setPetShop(PetShop petShop, boolean add) {
    this.petShop= petShop;
    if (petShop!= null && add) {
      petShop.addPet(this, false);
    }
}
```

**PetShop Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pet_shop")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class PetShop {

  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  ...

  @OneToMany(
      mappedBy = "petShop",
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
      cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  private List<Pet> pets= new ArrayList<>();

  public void addPet(final Pet pet) {
    addPet(pet, true);
  }

  public void addPet(final Pet pet, boolean set) {
    if (pet!= null) {
      if (pets.contains(pet)) {
        pets.set(pets.indexOf(pet), pet);
      } else {
        pets.add(pet);
      }
      if (set) {
        pet.setPetShop(this, false);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**PetShopRepository Interface**

```
public interface PetShopRepository 
  extends JpaRepository<PetShop, Long> {

  @Query(
      "SELECT DISTINCT ps FROM PetShop ps"
          + " JOIN ps.pets p"
          + " WHERE ps.id = :id AND p.deathDate IS NULL")
  @Override
  Optional<PetShop> findById(@NonNull Long id);
}
```

... and here is how to create a `PetShop` with 2 `Pet` instances (one alive and another one dead):

```
final Pet alive = new Pet();
alive.setName("cat");
alive.setCall("meow");
alive.setBirthDate(LocalDate.now());

final Pet dead = new Pet();
dead.setName("cat");
dead.setCall("meow");
dead.setBirthDate(LocalDate.now().minusYears(15L));
dead.setDeathDate(LocalDate.now());

final PetShop petShop = new PetShop();
petShop.getPets().add(alive);
petShop.getPets().add(dead);

petShopRepositiry.save(petShop);
```

Now I want to retrieve the `PetShop` and I'd assume it contains only pets that are **alive**:

```
final PetShop petShop = petShopRepository.findById(shopId)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new ShopNotFoundException(shopId));

final int petCount = petShop.getPets().size(); // expected 1, but is 2
```

According to my custom query in `PetShopRepository` I'd expect `petShop.getPets()` returns a list with 1 element, but it actually returns a list with 2 elements (it includes also the dead pet).

```
Am I missing something? Any hint would be really appreciated :-)
```

Comment: JPA deals with managed entities, so providers are expected to track changes made to entities returned from queries. If you get only partial data in your managed entity, and you clear that list - what does that mean to the elements that weren't in the collection? Such behavior is undefined, as is partial fetching when dealing with managed entities as it is to complex to manage everyones expectations and use cases. JPA covers it by allowing you to have queries return (and build) pojo objects with constructor queries, it just doesn't have a good mechanism for returning lists you'd use in objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Jpa maintains the coherence of the relations despite your query.

I.e. : your query returns the shops having at least one pet alive. But, Jpa will return the shop with the complete set of pets. And you can probably see extra sql queries sent by Jpa (if you set `show_sql=true`) to refill pets collection on the returned shop.

Fundamently, it's not because you wanted to get the shops with living pets that these shops loose their dead pets.

To get it right you would have to design the pets collection so that it would filter the dead pets. Hibernate provides such annotations (`@Filter` and `@FilterDef`), but apparently JPA does not.

I don't think that filtering at `@Postload` would be a good idea, because you would have to put back the filtered dead pets in the collection before any flush in the database. That looks risky to me.

Comment: Tried `@Filter` and `FilterDef`... but I still get all the pets.

Comment: Seems to be @Where on collections : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700071/how-to-use-where-in-hibernate