# Conditional uniqness

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have two tables/entities. Company, Office. Company has many officies, but only one is main office - has flag main = true.

How can I ensure that only one office for given company has flag main=true.

I know I can add additional table as I ve seen here:
[How to Select Only Specific Children in One to Many Relation in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74459126/how-to-select-only-specific-children-in-one-to-many-relation-in-jpa)

But maybe there is another way, some validation in JPA?

Comment: This is a DBMS specific question. So, which DBMS are you using?  (Please read the [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/SQL) tag for details.) Though, personally, I wouldn't have a flag for this, I'd have a `main_office_id` foreign key in the Company table. That's the typical pattern for "has zero or one" relationships.

Comment: You need a filtered unique constraint on `CompanyOffice (CompanyId) WHERE (main = TRUE)`

Comment: Make the attribute nullable.  Store 1 (for example) for main office and null otherwise.  Create unique index on company,headoffice.  In oracle it will work without anything else.  In sqlserver use filtered unique index